# Cannot locate the textfield when python selenium script is run

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a textfield on a web page that I want to feed data with but the problem is my python-selenium script is not able to locate it when it runs and reaches that page. The weird part is when i try to locate this textfield manually, I am able to do so without any problem. I am using CSSSelector to locate this field.

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/SWInstallation/TestCases/TestCases\Program.py", line 23, in test_UC_QS_FR_01_1_QuikShip_Support
bhp.enterAccDetails("0004341080", "00200")
File "C:\SWInstallation\HC-Branch\src\HomePage.py", line 24, in enterAccDetails
accInputField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fields input[name='ACCOUNT_NUMBER']")
File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 366, in find_element_by_css_selector
return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 680, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 158, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u"Unable to find element with css selector == #fields input[name='ACCOUNT_NUMBER']"
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML of the page and the code that you're using to locate the element?

Usually the first thing to consider is that perhaps that page was not loaded fully loaded yet, so the element was not found.  Adding the appropriate wait could solve the issue.

Comment: @PocketDews: Sorry but I cannot share the HTML page due to restrictions in my company. However I can share my code that I am using to locate the element.

Comment: Here it is:
def enterAccDetails(self, acctNumber, brNumber):
        accInputField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fields input[name='ACCOUNT_NUMBER']")
        accInputField.send_keys(acctNumber)
        
        brInputField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fields input[name='BRANCH']")
        brInputField.send_keys(brNumber)
        
        nextButton = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fields .htmlbutton")
        nextButton.click()

Comment: You could try another locator, xpath for example, and see if it helps

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich: Thanks for the advice but I did try and I got the same problem.. Still stuck up. :(

Comment: It becomes too difficult to help you without seeing the html code. Tell me two things:
1. Are you using implicitly waits?
2. Is the form containing you text filed static? I mean maybe some js draws or smth?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich: I could manage to get this piece of HTML:
<td align="right">Client</td>
<td>
<td align="right">RT</td>
<td>
<td align="right">Acct</td>
<td>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return allowNumOnly(event)" value="" onblur="isAccountNumberNumeric()" name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER" size="15"/>
</td>
<td align="right">Br</td>
<td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>

Comment: To answer what you asked:
1. I am using selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait
2. Yes the field is static

Comment: I don't know... Locator seems to be right. If locating your filed is the first action after getting the page, try
`import time`
`time.sleep(5)` after driver.get('your_url')

Comment: Or you may try to locate an element in another way:`element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver : self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fields input[name='ACCOUNT_NUMBER']']"))`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich: Still not getting it correct. Don't know what is the problem. Still feels like something is wrong!

Comment: What exception do you get, and what example do you use? And, sorry, I've made a mistake in last one (wrong locator). try `element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver : self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fields input[name='ACCOUNT_NUMBER']"))`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich: Here is the code I have written.

Comment: 'class BranchHomePage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        
    def enterAccDetails(self, acctNumber, brNumber):
        accInputField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='ACCOUNT_NUMBER']") 
        accInputField.send_keys(acctNumber)
        
        brInputField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fields input[name='BRANCH']")
        brInputField.send_keys(brNumber)
        
        nextButton = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fields .htmlbutton")
        nextButton.click()'

Comment: @Praveen and it doesn't work?
In my previous comment I gave an example of tricky element location/ Try to use it

Comment: This is the main program:
import unittest
from Browser import Browser
from BranchLogin import BranchLogin
from HomePage import BranchHomePage

class TestID_7935(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = Browser().createBrowserDriver()
        self.driver.set_window_size(900, 1000)
    def test_UC_QS_FR_01_1_QuikShip_Support(self):
        bl = BranchLogin(self.driver)
        bl.login("checkit", "Ch3cksico", "00319")
        bhp = BranchHomePage(self.driver)
        bhp.enterAccDetails("0004341080", "00200")
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
        #self.driver.quit()

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich: Just wanted to give you one more information. May be it helps you to help me. :)The field in which I have to set data (Accouny Number) does not accept values other than numbers even if we type alphabets on the key board.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich: I even used your solution after you made a correction. It does not work. The field which I am trying to fill data with is the very first element that I need to interact with post log in. So I also tried with giving some sleep top the page but even that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
e = self.driver.find_element_by_id("fields")
inputs = e.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[name='ACCOUNT_NUMBER']")
```

Comment: @Praveen Could you give me a sample similar to your HTML code; I know that you can't relieve information about codes in detail, just a general structure that I can guess how to access the element.

Comment: You can have any web page with a few text fields in it which I have very easily been able to locate. Something is strange in this particular text field

Comment: Of course; that's the reason I asked you for your own HTML code. Anyway, another approach came into my mind; have you tried this: `e = self.driver.find_element_by_id("fields"); inputs = e.find_elements_by_tag_name("input"); inputs = [element for element in inputs if element.get_attribute("name") == "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"]; desired_input = inputs[0];`